How to make 'Save' button to save HTML Input (type="text") value to seperate .txt file (JavaScript)
I have issues with making 'Save' button to save my HTML Input (type="text") value to seperate .txt file.
Can someone with enough JavaScript experience and knowledge help me with this problem, thanks in advance.
I wrote my HTML code for both input and button
<input class="test" type="text" id="test1" value="123">
<button class="savebutton">Save</button>


You can use the following code to save the text to a .txt file.
<input class="test" type="text" id="test1" value="123">
<button class="savebutton">Save</button>
<span style="font-family: Arial;" id="errorMsg" hidden><br />The value is not defined, you cant save it</span>

<script>
document.querySelector('button.savebutton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    const txt = document.querySelector('input.test#test1').value.trim();
    const errorElem = document.querySelector('span#errorMsg');
    if (!txt.length) { // The string is empty
        errorElem.hidden = false; // make the element visible
        return;
    }
    errorElem.hidden = true; // hide the elem if string is valid
    // make a data url out of the text
    const url = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa(txt);
    // create a element that is hidden and used to download the file at the url
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    a.download = "myfile.txt";
    a.click(); // click the element from js to download the file
    a.remove(); // remove the element
});
</script>

Explanation
In this example, we take the text in the input field and trim it (remove prefix and suffix whitespaces) and we check if the string is not empty. If it's empty then we show the error message and if it's empty then we create a data url using the btoa method and then we create an a element that has the href set to the url we generated using btoa and the download filename to myfile.txt. Then we click the element to start the download and remove the element. We also made an error element that has Arial font.
Please note that when using fonts, the user should also have that font installed on their system for it to display, else the default font will be used. You can also import font-face and use the font.
I hope this helps.

Thanks a lot for helping me out with this, but when I wrote this code into my program, this JS function can't be executed (Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node' : 1 argument required, but only 0 present.). I think that this 'appendChild' is reffered as line 8 in your answer. Can you help me fix this, thanks in advance

There is no reason to append the element to the DOM. So you can eliminate... a.hidden; ... document.body.appendChild(a); ... a.remove();

@RayWallace oh thanks, i didnt know the .click works even if the element is not in the DOM.

I have one more issue here, if input value is not defined (if its not written) , how to make code that will write under the input element "Value is not defined, you can't save it." with text styles such as font-family etc (f.e. try to use Arial just to show me example, to how to edit styles in JS).

@jordimetil I have updated the code to match your requireements.
